# Cannot use sudo apt update due to realese file issues

Tags: repository, updates, apt

[Terminal of me trying to use sudo update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhgY8.png)

Hi, I am new to linux and have recently migrated from linux mint to Ubuntu, I have been having lots of troubleshooting issues recently, mainly with these release files error, this is not the first instance I get this error, sometimes I will try to add an apt repository and get the exact same error, but this issues has escalated to the point where I cannot update.

What I did:

I used sudo apt update as a following to some advice I saw online to add a package to my machine.

What I expected:

I expected a simple update

What happened:

I got a release files error